# When my page loads I cannot pass the value of an element to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

```
$('body').load(
  // Handler for .load() called.
  amazingfunction("#chairleg");
);

function amazingfunction(str){
    // do ajax stuff with the variable
    // this bit works fine. I just want to auto load the element into this.
}
```

Can someone please help? I am trying to take the html content of #chairleg immediately the page loads, and call the function 'amazingfunction' straightaway whilst passing the variable.

I seem to be getting nowhere. I also tried it with the following instead of line 3, but no luck still:

```
$("#chairleg").html;
```

Strangely, I also seem to be getting errors when i have a semi colon  like  '  ; '   at the end of line 3. any ideas about these two issues? I guess they are linked and issue 2 will be solved once issue 1 is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
   amazingfunction($("#chairleg").html());
});

function amazingfunction(htm){
    //you have the html of chairleg in htm variable
    // do ajax stuff with the variable
    // this bit works fine. i just want to auto load the element into this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide callback functions.  You aren't actually creating functions...

Also, the `body` doesn't have a `load` event (although it does have an `onload` attribute).  Use `document` and its `ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    amazingfunction("#chairleg");
);
```

To get the HTML content of an element, use `$('selector').html()`.  So here you might use

```
amazingfunction($('#chairleg').html());
```